# Running and getting output from VB.NET Application through PHP Script

Tags: php, vb.net

I have my PHP application which is supposed to connect to a Third Party Software, to get and update data.

To connect to the Target Third Party (TP) Software, a VB.NET application to be written which will use with the software DLLs to update or get data from the TP Software.

I tried developing a EXE using VB.NET Windows Forms Application, but it does not give output in my PHP Code when run using EXEC()

Can someone guide me if what i am doing is correct method or i am missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Please put more information about the error, are you having any error?

Comment: No i am not getting any error. While debugging, the debugger stops at EXEC command line and Task Manager shows the EXE running, but nothing happens.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to call your php inside you vb.net program? or call you vb.net program inside your php?

Comment: @Simo, I want to call VB.NET program inside PHP Script

Comment: And I guess that you want to pass to the vb.net program some values right?

Comment: @Simo, yes, i am passing it like this -

Comment: @Simo, exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\myPHPApp\\TPI\\Guess\\myGuessConnector.exe /GET_ITEM /24",$Output)

Comment: did you tried to save your values inside a db and read them programmatically from the vb app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179631/discussion-between-ss-mj-and-simo).

Comment: @ss_mj maybe this could help you [PHP and .NET](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=27291)